# how to clear data of useState when route get changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have maintained state by using useState hook in react. I want to clean value that is getting maintain in state when route get changes.

For example - I have 4 routes declared in react based project. which are as below

```
<Router>
    <Layout>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
      <Route exact path="/defineFacilities" component={DefineFacilities}></Route>
      **<Route exact path="/createNewModel/:id" component={ModelFormsContainer}></Route>**
      <Route exact path="/viewExistingModels" component={ViewExistingModels}></Route>
      <Route exact path="/importNewModel" component={ImportNewModel}></Route>
    </Layout>
```

I have maintained state in ModelFormsContainer component. I want to clean state values when user move to other routes. Currently when I move to other route and back ModelFormsContainer component then I noticed that my state are still available.

Comment: either set it to an empty string or null right after you decide to move to another page

Comment: use the  cleanup function in useEffect hook .
it calls when the component unmounts.
in this function you can set your state to null.
BTW react destroys the state when unmounting a component.

Comment: @MhkAsif yes, useEffect is working when first time setState for new form, but get fail when when same component in edit mode (mean fill the state based on save data into database) and when try to change route and come back the component then my state is not getting clean.        const [formState, setFormState] = useState<IFormState>(defaultValueFormState);
    useEffect(()=>{
console.log('useEffect')
        return ()=>{
    setFormState(defaultValueFormState);
        }    
      },[])

Comment: The local component state is dumped and `ModelFormsContainer` unmounted when changing routes. There seems to be something else going on here. Can you add all the relevant code to your question? Can you share `ModelFormsContainer` component and what it does when mounted, and when the route changes. What is the edit mode doing?

Comment: I agree with @DrewReese , seems odd that the component is not unmounted. Maybe try using `children` instead of the `component` prop: `<Route exact path="/createNewModel/:id"><ModelFormsContainer /></Route>`. The docs on that prop are a little bit unclear to me. https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component

Comment: Thanks everyone. I get resolved by using useEffect. My problem was that my child type/props were not get clean. I just declare global variable to setup initial values of all fields and reset the default values for child type and set state in useEffect for global variable,

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to [reproduce the issue you describe](http://%5B!%5BEdit%20how-to-clear-data-of-usestate-when-route-get-changed%5D(https://codesandbox.io/static/img/play-codesandbox.svg)%5D(https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-clear-data-of-usestate-when-route-get-changed-x67dx?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark)), but if you need to do something when the route changes you can listen for changes to the route/location via the `history` object.

[history.listen](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#historylistenlistener-listener)

> Starts listening for location changes and calls the given callback
> with an Update when it does.
>
> ```
> // To start listening for location changes...
> let unlisten = history.listen(({ action, location }) => {
>   // The current location changed.
> });
>
> // Later, when you are done listening for changes...
> unlisten();
> ```

In the `ModelFormsContainer` access the passed history prop instantiate a listener when the component mounts, pass it a callback that updates the state.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unlisten = history.listen(() => {
    console.log("route changed!!");
    // apply business logic to set any component state
  });
  console.log("ModelFormsContainer mounted");

  return unlisten;
}, []);
```

If `ModelFormsContainer` is a class component then obviously use `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` and save `unlisten` as a class instance variable, i.e. `this.unlisten`.